# Any solution for redundancy at the server level for small business?

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012

Back in 2009, we have a solution as follow:

1. Physical Server called Server1 with HyperV and has 1 virtual server - Server3 - running file server, web and application
2. Physical Server called Server2 with HyperV and has 1 virtual server - Server4 - running Dedicated SQL and MySQL Server
3. No shred storage.
4. Use the DoubleTake software to cross continuos sync virtualisation of these 2 virtual server.

The idea is that if one of the server goes down we can just flick the virtual server within few minutes.

Now that was 2009 and since Windows 2012 around, is there any other solution to do this redundancy and availability like above?

Does Windows 2012 has similar function like DoubleTake does (sync continuous availability) perhaps?

I'm appreciated your feedback

Thanks

Comment: You could certainly use Hyper-V Replica between the two hosts to provide a level of redundancy close to what DT gave you. - http://blogs.technet.com/b/yungchou/archive/2013/01/10/hyper-v-replica-explained.aspx

Comment: So I don't need the shared storage (SAN/direct storage) ... do I? How's the replication sync then? Every few minutes?

Comment: Hyper-V Replica does not require shared storage. Read the article I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

DoubleTake was a good solution in 2009, but it's quite expensive and was fickle.

Both VMWare and Microsoft have standalone replication (called "Shared Nothing"), but they operate differently.

I would certainly look at upgrading to Server 2012 R2 to get access to Hyper-V Replicas for shared-nothing redundancy.

Comment: Hyper-V Replica is available in Windows Server 2012.

Comment: We are looking at have brand new boxes and new OS. But due to limited budget ... we can't afford it to shared storage. Does this one needs to have a shared storage?

Comment: Nope. Hyper-V replica only needs a network, but will force you to do manual failovers. The next version of Windows will feature shared nothing storage spaces that will even enable clustering without shared storage.